# Deploying/Updating Marathon Docker image using API

Tags: python, rest, docker, marathon

I am writing code to update deployed image on marathon automatically. I use the REST patch method as listed in marathon API reference http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/api-console/index.html

```
    url = 'https://<my-hostname>:<my-port>/v2/apps'
    h = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    data = {'app': { "id": app,
                'container': {
                    'docker': {
                        'image': image}}}}
    print ('requests.patch(%s, %s)' % (url + app, json.dumps(data)))
    r = requests.patch(url + app, headers = h, auth = auth, data = json.dumps(data))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Deployed %s' % app)
```

The code ran successfully, I got back a Deployment ID, but nothing was changed from the UI. No new deployment is happening. If I change the patch request into get request without the data, I get back the image I previous updated in using code above.

According to this similar API reference https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/deploying-services/marathon-api/#/apps/V2AppsByAppId1

It says " This operation will create a deployment" but nothing happened. From the Marathon GUI, I don't see the configuration getting changed at all. If I restart, it is the same old deployment getting restarted. Am I interpreting the API reference incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the API reference guide correctly, the body should be:

```
{ "id": app,
  "container": {
       "docker": {
          "image": image
        }
   }
}
```

Tested this with marathon 1.4.11 and that worked.
Not sure why you would get a deploymentid, if I do it the way you did (with the extra {"app":} layer), I get a 500 error. BTW, I am not sure how sensitive this is for single versus double quotes.

Comment: I felt so stupid! You are right. I have that extra "app" enclosure. I'm not sure where I get it from. Removing the app layer just works!

Comment: I know why. When I made the GET request, the result is stored inside the "app" enclosure. I just assumed I should use the same format when patching.

Answer (score 0):

There is [open bug](https://jira.d2iq.com/browse/MARATHON-7871) in Marathon which cause that request body is not merged with current definition. Therefore, *PUT*/*PATCH* request with only `.container.docker.image` will remove settings like *port mappings*, *volumes*, *parameters*...

Solution is to get `container` object from current application and replace `image` key with new Docker image.

Example:

```sh
export MARATHON_IMAGE="registry.foo.bar/app:v10"

export BODY=$(curl -s -H "Content-type: application/json" leader.mesos:8080/v2/apps/foo/bar | jq -cr '.app.container | .docker.image = env.MARATHON_IMAGE | {"container": .}')

curl -s -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PATCH -d "${BODY}" leader.mesos:8080/v2/apps/foo/bar
```